# How to set initial value with styled component props

Tags: styled-components

I am making app using styled components.

I would like to pass some props to position my element

In a situation where no props gets passed I want to set a value initial

Of course if I do something like in example I get error

```
Cannot find name 'initial'.ts(2304)
```

```js
<SomeStyledComponent top="20px" />
```

```js
const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(props) => props.top || initial} !important;
`
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(props) => props.top ? props.top : initial} !important;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You get error because variable with name "initial" has not been defined.

You can define initial value direct in component.

In fourth variant , i show how fix error in your example.

```
// first variant
const Component = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(p) => `${p.top || 20}px`};
`

// second variant
const Component = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(p) => `${p.top}px`};
`

Component.defaultProps = {
  top: 200
}

// third variant, set default value in wrapper component
const BaseComponent = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(p) => `${p.top}px`};
`;

const Component = ({ top = 50, children, ...rest }) => (
  <BaseComponent top={top} {...rest}>
    {children}
  </BaseComponent>
);

// fourth variant, your example with fix

const initial = "200px"

const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(props) => props.top || initial} !important;
`
```